# Newline in constant error while fetching the data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fetch the value from db

var Link = el.Element("link").Value;

```
<div class="hotspot" link="<%=Link%>" style="background-image:url('/content/images/site/clearpixel.gif');z-index:4000;position:absolute;cursor:pointer;top:<%=Top%>px;left:<%=Left%>px;width:<%=Width%>px;height:<%=Height%>px;"></div>
```

I am getting the error ' newline in constant error. How to get rid of this error

Object reference not set to an instance of an object in this line :

```
foreach (var el in slide.Hotspots.Elements())
```

Link does not exist in the current contest

```
 <div class="hotspot" link="<%=Link%>" style="background-image:url('/content/images/site/clearpixel.gif');z-index:4000;position:absolute;cursor:pointer;top:"<%=Top%>"px;left:"<%=Left%
```

Comment: After your edit - you're getting a `NullReferenceException` there - which means one of `slide` or `slide.Hotspots` or `slide.Hotspots.Elements` is null. That would get thrown as a runtime exception if everything compiles, and your `newline in constant` is a compilation error, which appears to be unrelated to the code you've shown. Which one is occurring?

Comment: For code see my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645056/how-to-fetch-the-values-from-database

Comment: the accepted answer does not solve your first bug. what are you going to do?! you solved first bug then updated your question and he solved the 2nd bug!

Comment: This is unethical at all. you supposed to post a new question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your other question, your problem is that you're trying to write HTML while you're still in a C# context.

When you're using the `<% %>` syntax, everything between those symbols (or `<%=` or `<%:` or whatever) is C#, not HTML. This is unlike Razor, where you can mix-and-match C# and HTML code a little more.

So the reason you're getting the newline problem is that the `<div...` that you've got is trying to get compiled as C#, and obviously it fails. Move it out of the code block and you'll be fine, something like:

```
<%
    foreach (var el in slide.Hotspots.Elements()) { 
        var Top = el.Element("top").Value;
        var Left = el.Element("left").Value;
        var Width = el.Element("width").Value;
        var Height = el.Element("height").Value;
        var Link = el.Element("link").Value;
 %>
 <div ...></div>
 <% } %>
```